# How to get checked row of data grid in java script?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using the DataGrid control with template columns.
I m getting the data in datagrid but I'm having trouble accessing the data of checked row using java script.
How can i achive dis using java script?

Comment: please be more specific && post some code, relevant to your question ...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the exact implementation of your data grid but this is how we check it using javascript:

```
if (document.getElementById('checkbox_id_here').checked == true)
{
  // yes it is checked
}
else
{
  // no it is not checked
}
```